# laravel 9 smtp gmail .env setup

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

i am a bit stuck here, I have done this before, so I have a registration form that sends mail after the registration is completed , I have tested with default mailtrap and it works, i just have to replace the details to Gmail. and I have done it all, it turns out Gmail has turned of less secure feature from the Gmail setting, these settings allow less secure apps to send mails

here is my .env config

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my email
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="my email"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

i have also tried creating an app password and replacing that with the password above , it doesnt work , i get the error

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "develaustin@gmail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.9 Application
```

please i need any suggestion . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<Enter your Gmail address>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<Enter your Gmail password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="your name"
```

that error happened because : you need to enable this but it's no longer available [image: screeshot]

You can try free plan of mailtrap.io if you want it for testing

i hope it was useful

Comment: thank you so much for the response, yes thats no longer available and i tried your suggestion with the ssl, but still the same, i have tested with mailtrap , i want to go live with it , and i cant use mailtrap anymore